# Sirikit supported services and its extended usage

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit

I have a roadside assistance service application. It has some of the functionalities similar to ride booking app(Eg. Uber). How far can i leverage iOS 10 Sirikit? May be, apple can reject it. But i need to know the technical feasibility.

My application's functionality - I am struck in the middle of road with a flat tire. I need a tow assistance for my car. I give my current location and i ask my app to tow to my preferred dealer location. I pay for the service and wait for the provider to respond. I receive continuous updates from my service provider regarding the driver.

1st Step tried: I am trying to open my app with the statement "Siri, get a roadside assistance for my flat tire". I need to open my app and capture FLAT TIRE as a parameter. But I couldn't.

I tried using AppIntentVocabulary.plist. It was not working. I am missing something and there are no complete tutorials over the internet. Any help is much appreciated.

Sample Project:
Github Link for my simple Siri Integration:
https://github.com/vivinjeganathan/SiriExample

Answer (score 0):

```
This documentation contains preliminary information about an API or technology in development. This information is subject to change, and software implemented according to this documentation should be tested with final operating system software.

SiriKit is a way for you to make your content available through Siri. It also lets you add support for your services to the Maps app. To support SiriKit, you use the Intents framework and Intents UI framework to implement one or more extensions that you then include inside your iOS app. When the user requests specific types of services through Siri or Maps, the system uses your extensions to provide those services.

Add SiriKit support only if your app implements one of the following types of services:

Audio or video calling

Messaging

Payments

Searching photos

Workouts

Ride booking

Check this Link: http://airflypan.com/foundation-course/233
```

http://airflypan.com/foundation-course/233

Comment: Please give me exact information required. I have already gone through the generic implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

You really can't do this in any sensible way for the user. Although you app's usecase will map to ride-hailing intent the vocabulary will not. Siri gives you almost no options to influence the vocabulary she is using to communicate to your User. If you could only teach you users that requesting a tow is actually requesting a ride... :)

Apple have analyzed the domains they are supporting and the vocabulary that is used in these domains and "taught" them to Siri in every language/culture that Siri is supporting. This makes total sense from Apple's point of view because you'd be hard pressed to be able to do this yourself.

Comment: Ok. What is the use of AppIntentVocabulary.plist?

Comment: @vivin You can define _proper names_ in AppIntentVocabulary that Siri will then understand when spoken to her and can speak them back. You can only define them for workout names ("jumping jacks") and ride options ("sportscar"). https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/SpecifyingCustomVocabulary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH6-SW1